# Google analytics chrome campaign plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics

I post a lot of links via facebook/twitter for my website.  I'd like to assign campaigns to them, but it's such a pain to login to GA and create a campaign.

I'm looking for a chrome/firefox plugin (or simple desktop app) to create the campaign links for me based on the link I want to send out.

I haven't found this on Google so I was wondering if anyone knows of a tool that does this.

Comment: There isn't one, perhaps you can use [Bitly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iabeihobmhlgpkcgjiloemdbofjbdcic) Chrome extension to share. Bitly keeps tracks of analytics (well, on a limited level anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found snip-n-tag for firefox.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/snip-n-tag/

It shortens your URL and adds a campaign link to it.  I couldn't find one for chrome.